# Maven scope - provided, but spring-boot-starter-webflux dependencies included in compiled jar. Why?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I want to build jar file library and not include dependencies, as they will be in class path of application which will use this library. I use **maven scope - provided** for that and all dependencies are excluded but few still left. I found they come from **spring-boot-starter-webflux**. Why it this? And what should I do to get rid of them?

Here the dependency example

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Nevertheless provided scope some jars from this dependency
     are in compiled jar file. Why ? -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Sample project with just this one dependency is on https://github.com/pavelmorozov/MavenProvidedTest/blob/master/pom.xml

Empty compiled project jar have 5+ megabytes size.

**Update** After **JF Meier** suggestion, I tried **mvn dependency:tree** and found two libraries with scope compile

```
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:provided
[INFO]    |  \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:jar:0.8.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.33.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.33.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.33.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.33.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     |  |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.33.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.33.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.33.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.33.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.33.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.33.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.33.Final:compile
[INFO]    |        \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.33.Final:compile
...
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO]    |  \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.2:compile
```

And for example I see one of POM files

```
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.5.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Now I still not get why other Spring Boot included libraries not override **scope** to **compile**. Does it means this two libraries build wrong or they build this way for some reason? And I still not clear how to remove in simple way dependencies that seems have override scope?

I tried to put version number in my POM dependency - but this have no effect - same jars included in compiled project jar:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Update about parents**

Parent pom file **spring-boot-starter-parent** not contains any **dependencyManagement** section, but have one more parent - **spring-boot-dependencies** - and it does have **dependencyManagement** section but scope compiled there is not provided. Some of dependencies have scope import though. I not understand could this import scoped dependencies have effect in my case. Some samples from here:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty</artifactId>
           <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>
       ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${reactor-bom.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
       ...
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The part of content of **spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty** i posted here in previous update.

**Update** after **Andy Wilkinson** answer just to clarify - such dependencies are not included in jar, seems spring boot maven plugin do its work in different way here:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

A Spring Boot fat jar is intended to contain everything that's required to run the application. You can't use `-jar` and `-classpath` at the same time when launching the JVM, so that means that the jar needs to contain provided dependencies as well as there's no other way for them to get onto the classpath.

This behaviour is described in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/maven-plugin/usage.html) for Spring Boot's Maven Plugin where it says the following:

> The example above repackages a jar or war that is built during the package phase of the Maven lifecycle, including any provided dependencies that are defined in the project.

If you don't want your application's jar to have any dependencies packaged inside it, i.e. you want it to be a normal jar rather than a fat jar, then you probably do not want to use Spring Boot's Maven plugin to build it. If you remove it from your sample project's `pom.xml` file and then build it, the resulting jar has the following contents:

```
$ unzip -l target/MavenProvidedTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
Archive:  target/MavenProvidedTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      329  02-22-2019 11:33   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
        0  02-22-2019 11:33   META-INF/
        0  02-22-2019 11:33   META-INF/maven/
        0  02-22-2019 11:33   META-INF/maven/io.spring/
        0  02-22-2019 11:33   META-INF/maven/io.spring/MavenProvidedTest/
        1  02-22-2019 11:33   application.properties
     1403  02-22-2019 11:33   META-INF/maven/io.spring/MavenProvidedTest/pom.xml
      101  02-22-2019 11:33   META-INF/maven/io.spring/MavenProvidedTest/pom.properties
---------                     -------
     1834                     8 files
```

If you want some but not all of the dependencies to be included, then you could continue to use Spring Boot's Maven Plugin and [exclude](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/exclude-dependency.html) some dependencies instead.

Comment: The docs link is for 2.1.3.RELEASE while I use 1.5.6.RELEASE with <layout>MODULE</layout>. I am still on java 8 and used to have library jars this way. This module layout is not in 2.x version (remember we discussed the docs update with you). Layout module means not runnable jar - but library. So I not need java -jar at all. Any way I will try your idea to remove Spring Boot Maven plugin.

Comment: If you need the module layout, you should use Spring Boot 1.5 everywhere rather than using Spring Boot 2.1 and only downgrading the Maven Plugin. For the record, the 1.5 documentation also describes the behaviour with `provided` dependencies.

Comment: This means Spring Boot Maven plugin 1.x not compatible with Spring Boot 2.x. This is new for me - probably I miss something. I work on Spring Boot 2.x for a while but was not able to find the way to build a jar library with Spring Boot plugin 2.x and get back to 1.x plugin (I am still on java 8). Also see update in my question - I just tried with other dependencies and they are not included in jar.

Comment: I don't understand the significance of you still being on Java 8. Spring Boot 2.x supports Java 8.

Comment: As I understood module layout was removed in spring boot maven plugin 2.x because newer java 9 have modules.

Comment: I removed spring boot maven plugin from all projects I not run, and  - jars now are pretty and small. I tried to have scope optional and not have scope at all - this seems have no effect. I left Spring boot maven plugin 2.x only in dependent application - and this one I will run. I tried and all seems works fine. **Thank you for your help!** Though I still not get why spring-boot-starter-web not includes anything if scope provided, but some of dependencies from spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty are included. Cannot get deeper as already spend a lot of time with it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the parent pom has a `dependencyManagement` section that overwrites scopes/versions.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your idea. I tried to check dependencies pom files and updated my question. I still not clear about why is scope overridden just in few libraries and how to deal with it.

Comment: Frankly, I do not understand what you tried (in your edit). My suggestion was: Go to spring-boot-starter-parent, which is your parent, and look whether it has a `<dependencyManagement>` section. Look if it sets some of the dependencies that are unexpectedly "compile" instead of "provided".

Comment: Hello. Yes, I probably doing something strange, because not understand all of this. Parent not have such section <dependencyManagement>, but it have one more parent and scope compiled there not used at all. Some of dependencies have scope import though.

Comment: Dependencies without a scope have implicitly scope compile. Scope import imports a list from the defined file (so look up the dependencies there).

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to understand how this works and give up. Thanks for your efforts though.

Comment: If you cannot find the troubling dependencies, you can still overwrite the scope by listing the relevant artifacts in the `<dependencyManagement>` section with the desired scope. This takes some time, but you can be sure that your dependencyManagement is stronger than the definitions in the parent POM.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that you need a thin executable jar. For you may use [spring-thin-launcher](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-thin-launcher) plugin. It will exclude the dependencies to be packaged as part of the jar but will download from maven during first run or you may provide your own local repo where all the jar files can be found.

For details refer to this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-thin-jar)